# Not enough horizontal space for image uploader on some localized sites

Tags: bug, design, localization, uploader, responsive-design

For instance, on [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) as well as on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) there's not enough horizontal space for the image uploader in responsive design on my phone:

> [image: esSO]

> [image: ruSO]

Comment: This is also the case here on MSE. So definetly not a localisation issue.

Comment: @Luuklag what's your device resolution? [No repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVuQO.png) for me on MSE.

Comment: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4gE5.jpg) of repro. Resolution is 1080*2240 according to google (Huawei P20 Pro)

Comment: @Luuklag interesting. Is there a bug-report about that? BTW in your case even undo/redo buttons are absent in the toolbar.

Comment: This is easily reproducible everywhere with [Responsive Design Mode](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode).